# How to maximize performance when calculating the average of specific object properties?

Tags: javascript, average, object-literal

I want to calculate the average of *specific* object properties. To this end, I want to write my own custom function.

Two important notes are:

1. I preemptively know the exact keys on which to operate.
2. The values appear as string and need to be converted to numbers before mathematically operating on them.

Since I already know the keys, I thought I could save myself unneeded iterations, see in this example:

```js
const student = {
  age: "20",
  city: "kensas city",
  gender: "male",
  math101: "60.8",
  math223: "80.2",
  math840: "85.9",
  math100: "91.0",
  history101: "77.5",
  history224: "99.6",
  history554: "88.0",
};

const calcMeanMath1 = (obj) =>
  (obj.math100 + obj.math101 + obj.math223 + obj.math840) / 4;
```

But I need to convert to numbers first! So I can do this ugly thing:

```js
const calcMeanMath2 = (obj) =>
  (Number(obj.math100) +
    Number(obj.math101) +
    Number(obj.math223) +
    Number(obj.math840)) /
  4;
```

**My question**

I know there are alternatives. One is to `.map()` over the properties first and convert to numbers, then do the calculation. Other option is to use a `for` loop over each object property, convert to number on the spot, then accumulate to a sum.

All are good, but since I already know the names of the desired properties to operate on, isn't it wasteful to run over the *entire* object?

On the other hand, I'm unsure whether my `calcMeanMath2()` is an optimal option either. Also, what if I have 10 or 20 properties to calculate the average on? I would need to wrap each one with `Number()`.

Is there a way to take advantage of preemptively knowing the specific object properties, to maximize performance & speed?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, as in my `calcMeanMath2()` above?

Comment: Writing less code does not mean better performance

Comment: In terms of speed, `calcMean2()` is probably optimal. In terms of flexibility, what about e.g. `const keys = ["math101", "math223"] ; keys.reduce((s, x) => Number(student[x])) / keys.length` ?? Or you could store the values as numbers from the beginning.

Comment: I don't see what makes the version with the `Number` calls more ugly than the one without them. If it's just about verbosity, you can use unary plus instead: `(obj) => (+obj.math100 + +obj.math101 + +obj.math223 + +obj.math840) / 4;`

Answer (score 1):

Looping over specific set of keys would always be optimal. Say your object has 10^9 proprties. And you only need the sum of two properties.

You can create a function that accepts the object and an array of keys to loop over, sums their value and returns the mean.

---

### Example:

```js
const getMeanFromObject = (object, keys) => {
  if(keys.length == 0) return 0;
  const totalSum = keys.reduce((partialSum, key) => partialSum + (object[key] ?? 0) * 1, 0);
  return totalSum/keys.length;
}

const student = {
  age: "20",
  city: "kensas city",
  gender: "male",
  math101: "60.8",
  math223: "80.2",
  math840: "85.9",
  math100: "91.0",
  history101: "77.5",
  history224: "99.6",
  history554: "88.0",
};


console.log(getMeanFromObject(student, ["math101","math223","math840"]));
```

### Explanation:

1. `if(keys.length == 0) return 0;`

You don't wanna divide by zero if you accidently send an empty array.

2. `const totalSum = keys.reduce((partialSum, key) => partialSum + (object[key] ?? 0) * 1, 0);`

Returns the sum, read about `reduce` at [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). I can't probably explain it better than them.

3. `(object[key] ?? 0) * 1`

`??` is also know as nullish coalescing. Returns right-hand operand if left-hand operand is `null` or `undefined`. In case your if your key doesn't exists in the object, it would right the right hand side operand, that is `0` in this example.

If key exists, we would get string, multiply it with `1` to convert it to numerical value.